# Groupby, Window and rolling average in Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to do a groupby and do a rolling average on huge dataset using pyspark. Not used to pyspark I struggle to see my mistake here. Why doesn't this work?

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A']*5+['B']*5,
 'order':[1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5],
'value':[23, 54, 65, 64, 78, 98, 78, 76, 77, 57]})

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("order").rowsBetween(-1, 0)

# Calculate the rolling average of col_value
rolling_avg = avg(col("value")).over(window_spec).alias("value_rolling_avg")

# Group by col_group and col_date and calculate the rolling average of col_value
spark_df.groupby("group").agg(rolling_avg).show()
```

```
AnalysisException: [COLUMN_NOT_IN_GROUP_BY_CLAUSE] The expression "order" is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in `first()` (or `first_value()`) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing window functions and aggregation functions.

you can simply select `rolling_avg` to get your result :

```
spark_df.select(rolling_avg).show()

+-----------------+
|value_rolling_avg|
+-----------------+
|             23.0|
|             38.5|
|             59.5|
|             64.5|
|             71.0|
|             98.0|
|             88.0|
|             77.0|
|             76.5|
|             67.0|
+-----------------+
```

OR

```
spark_df.withColumn("value_rolling_avg", rolling_avg).show()

+------+------+------+-----------------+
|group_|order_|value_|value_rolling_avg|
+------+------+------+-----------------+
|     A|     1|    23|             23.0|
|     A|     2|    54|             38.5|
|     A|     3|    65|             59.5|
|     A|     4|    64|             64.5|
|     A|     5|    78|             71.0|
|     B|     1|    98|             98.0|
|     B|     2|    78|             88.0|
|     B|     3|    76|             77.0|
|     B|     4|    77|             76.5|
|     B|     5|    57|             67.0|
+------+------+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thx. Is it possible to combine groupBy and window at all?

Comment: @Henri No. If there is something you'd like to do and you don't know how to do it, just ask the question with proper input and expected output. But the very principle of window function is not compatible with group by. You can always first use the window then group by though